# Reusing CSS Shapes

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm new to CSS and HTML. When creating a CSS shape its position is defined in the actual CSS code. When using the shape in HTML, is there a way that I can modify the position so that I can reuse the same shape with different position attributes instead of having to declare another CSS shape for every new position?

```
.navbutton {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0em;
    top: 8em;
    width: 33%;
    height: 1.75em;
    background: red;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
}
```

If I was to make multiple nav buttons next to each other using this one how would I go about it?

Thanks.

Oh, and I don't know any other web language (Javascript, PHP, etc).

Comment: Not with `position: fixed` :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can see this link : [ReuseCSSnavButton](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_eirenaios/Lw4jW/)

THIS LINK FOR 3 BUTTONS [THREE LINKS](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_eirenaios/Lw4jW/1/)

html

---

```
 <div class="navbutton">first</div>
<div class="navbutton">second</div>
<div class="navbutton">third</div>
<div class="navbutton">fourth</div>
```

css

---

```
.navbutton {
position: relative;
float:left;
width: 100px;
height: 40px;
background: red;
color: black;
font-size: 1.5em;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 0.5em;
margin-right: 0.5em;
```

}

Comment: I believe he said he wanted it to be 33%... if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about float.

Comment: enjoy! Peace! Keep supporting! Voting!

Comment: How can I add a space between each button so that they aren't touching? There are three buttons and I'm trying to put a 1% space between the first + second and second + third.

Comment: USE MARGIN-RIGHT IN PERCENTAGE FOR EACH

Comment: i am glad that helped you! Enjoy Keep rocking

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple html elements with the .navbutton class, and then individually set their position using an inline style attribute like so:

```
<div class="navbutton" style="left:  5px; top: 20px;"></div>
<div class="navbutton" style="left: 20px; top:  5px;"></div>
<div class="navbutton" style="left:  8px; top: 13px;"></div>
```

If you want the navbuttons to display next to each other, you can put them in a container like so:

```
<div class="navbutton-container">
    <div class="navbutton">Button 1</div>
    <div class="navbutton">Button 2</div>
    <div class="navbutton">Button 3</div>
    <div class="navbutton">Button 4</div>
</div>
```

Then have each button float left which will display them next to each other, and have them wrap to the next line if they exceed the size of the container.

```
.navbutton-container {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0em;
    top: 8em;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbutton {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    height: 1.75em;
    background: red;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle showing the result: http://jsfiddle.net/sarathijh/mw96Q/

Comment: Just remember that it is not a good practice to use inline styles.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about float.

Answer (score 0):

Due to you could have different number buttons in your nav depending of the view where you are I recommend you to take of the width from the button class. Something like this ([Example](http://goo.gl/0Ia2Fw))
CSS

```
.navbutton {
    height: 1.75em;
    background: red;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    float:left;
}
.size-4buttons div
{
    width:25%;
}
```

HTML

```
<nav class="size-4buttons">
    <div class="navbutton">Button 1</div>
    <div class="navbutton">Button 2</div>
    <div class="navbutton">Button 3</div>
    <div class="navbutton">Button 4</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about float.

Answer (score -1):

`position: fixed` will break your flow.

Try something like this instead:

```
.navbutton {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    left: 0em;
    top: 8em;
    width: 33%;
    height: 1.75em;
    background: red;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jnbS5/2/

**3 identical shaped objects side-by-side :-)**

Add a margin if you want a break between them.

http://jsfiddle.net/jnbS5/1/

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about float. It's for the navigation bar though, so won't fixed be helpful for that purpose?

Comment: Wrap it in an absolute container.